# vector object inside another class initialization vector objects and access the vector objects

Tags: c++, stl

I am learning c++ beginner level.
Lets take an example.
I want to know how vector inside another class can be accessed, getters and setters usage for vector member.

```
class A{
    int id;
public :
    A(){
    }
    A(int id){
        id=id;
    }
    int get(){
        return id;
    }
    void set(int id1){
        id=id1;
    }

};
class B{
    vector <A> bb1;
};
```

How to create constructor, setter, getter for vector bb1.

Comment: On a basic level: copy the `int` example and replace `int` with `vector<A>`.

Comment: Don't. Getters and setters are unidiomatic in C++. Use a public member instead.

Comment: @L.F. how come? All standard library classes use getters like `x.size()`

Comment: @Ayxan Well, technically that is a getter. But size is a property of the container that cannot be modified separately. In my last comment I was referring to (hypothetical) getters and setters for e.g. first and second of std::pair, which are accessed using the member syntax directly instead. Even for tuple (which has to use a getter for technical reasons), we have one std::get function. I think in this case we don’t need a separate getter and setter. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like `int`, but be more careful to not make many copies:

```
class B {
private:
  vector<A> bb1;
public:
  B(vector<A> v) : bb1{std::move(v)} {}
  auto& get_vec() noexcept { return bb1; }
  auto const& get_vec() const noexcept { return bb1; }
  void set_vec(vector<A> v) { bb1 = std::move(v); }
};
```

---

#### Highlights:

- `noexcept` (in this context) roughly means this function won't throw. [Further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).
- `const` (in this context) means this function does not alter the state of the object. [Further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-_and_volatile-qualified_member_functions).
- `std::move` roughly speaking, "moves" resources of one object to other one. Generally saves you a copy. Of course `std::move` is vastly more complex than that. [Further reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Comment: Given the nature of the question I doubt that OP understands `std::move`, `noexcept`, `const`ness or the concept of references. Might add some explanation or further documentation aswell.

Comment: @Timo thank you for the feedback. I added short descriptions and links for further reading.